# Access 14.0 reference instead of Access 11.0

Tags: ms-access, reference, ms-access-2010

I have had this problem before but cannot remember or find and answer.

I have Access 2003 DB running then later Access 2010 was installed.

Now when open the Access 2003 app it has the Access 14.0 object library reference instead
of Access 11.0 reference.

You cannot change it in the References dialog as it says its "In Use"

So how can i change it back to  11.0.

Malcolm

Comment: Is it doing you any harm? You may wish to read http://allenbrowne.com/ser-38.html

Comment: You are opening a MDB file ... in Access 2007? No wonder it's an Access 14.0 reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change it while Access is running, you should then update the corresponding value in your registry. But, as said by #remou, is using Access 14 doing you any arm?